# Is MongoDB Realm function scalable?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-realm

I am pretty new to MongoDB.
I am in a scenario where it is possible for a system to invoke functions simultaneously many time.

I have gone through [mongoDB Atlas function documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/functions/#when-to-use-functions) and didn't find anything which speaks about scalability or concurrency issues.

Can a single function be invoked multiple times in parallel?
for example: Three different request trying to invoke same function will all three request be handled one by one or in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the functions concurrently, provided the workload adheres to the App Services' [limitation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/reference/service-limitations/#request-traffic) of 5000 concurrent requests. So, to address your point: if 3 different services try to invoke the same function at a time, they will be handled in parallel.

Additionally, you can use [HTTPS Endpoints](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/data-api/custom-endpoints/#create-a-custom-https-endpoint) to expose a Function and trigger it through an endpoint call.